# polymorphic association for element, anything else needs to be added?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have adopted and I'm not sure exactly why something isn't working.

I have a pricable polymorphic association which I use for only a single model called Item. It looks like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  #price
  has_one :price, :as => :pricable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :price

  attr_accessible :price_attributes, :price, ....
```

I'd like to add to an Event model and have added the following:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  #price
  has_one :price, :as => :pricable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :price
  attr_accessible :price, :price_attributes
```

However, I am not able to set it:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > e=Event.find(19) #ok
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > e.price
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method Price.page.
  Price Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `prices`.* FROM `prices` WHERE `prices`.`pricable_id` = 19 AND `prices`.`pricable_type` = 'Event' LIMIT 1
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > e.price.price=23
NoMethodError: undefined method `price=' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):3
```

Hmmm.... it looks like the relationship is set up correctly and that Event has access to price via attr_accessible. Any idea what else could be going on?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationship appears to be defined correctly, however if e.price returns nil then obviously e.price.price= won't work and return undefined method error. You need to build/create an associated price object first:

```
> e = Event.find(19)
=> #<Event id: 19, ...>
> e.price
=> nil
> e.create_price(price: 23)
=> #<Price id: 1, priceable_id: 19, price: 23, ...>
```

or if you would like to use nested attributes:

```
> e = Event.find(19)
=> #<Event id: 19, ...>
> e.price
=> nil
> e.update_attributes(price_attributes: { price: 23 })
=> true
> e.price
=> #<Price id: 1, priceable_id: 19, price: 23, ...>
```

Comment: cool, is build_price an alias for create_price? I was able to get working like 5 min after bounty. lol ...

Comment: build_price is not alias for create_price. The difference between them is that build_price only builds associated price object and does not save it to database while create_price builds price object and immediately saves it. Check [has_one](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one) documentation for details about build_association and create_association methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is how your models should look like

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :value
  belongs_to :priceable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :price_attributes
   has_one :price, :as => :priceable
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :price
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :price_attributes
  has_one :price, :as => :priceable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :price
end
```

This is how your price migration should look like

```
class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pictures do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.integer :imageable_id
      t.string  :imageable_type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And then you can easly do something like this

```
Item.new( { name: 'John', price_attributes: { value: 80 } } )
```